# Dealing with duplicates Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a case data CSV file. I am running into a problem wherein one of the columns named `case_number` there are multiple case number repeats. Is there a way to delete the duplicates without losing any of the information related to those rows that will be dropped.

In other words, merge all the information into one cell assigned to the `case_number`.

[image: Here is an image of the CSV]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give some code examples

Answer (score 2):

You should use `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')` to create your DataFrame, but for this simplified example, I'll just create one out of a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,1,2,2], 'y':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})
df = df.groupby('x')['y'].apply(lambda i: ', '.join(i)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   x           y
0  1  a, b, c, e
1  2     d, f, g
```

Replace `', '` with whatever separator you want between the strings.

Comment: Thank you, Sir I'm new to python. Have done tons of tutorials and practice sets but now as an intern, I no longer have my hand held. Having to apply these skills is a bit difficult but challenging ones self is the best way to learn.

Comment: @VictorAguilar - happy to help. If you're doing a lot of data processing like this, Pandas will come in extremely helpful. If you feel like I answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you check it as _the_ answer.